Can FluentD append the client certificate into the record
I'm trying to setup a FluentD service. It will append the metadata into the log record, such as timestamp, hostname, username, etc.
It is working with Mutual Authentication (self-signed) with HTTP input. Is it possible to append the tls client certificate's subject into the record?
My config currently like this:
<source>
  @type http
  port  8000
  bind  0.0.0.0

  <transport tls>
    client_cert_auth    true
    ca_path             /path/to/ca-crt.pem
    ca_private_key_path /path/to/ca-key.pem
    cert_path           /path/to/server-crt.pem
    private_key_path    /path/to/server-key.pem
  </transport>
</source>

<filter **>
  @type             record_transformer
  enable_ruby       true
  <record>
    _meta ${ {timestamp: time.strftime('%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%L%z'), host:Socket.gethostname} }
  </record>
</filter>

I cannot found any related information from offical document (in_http, with mutual-authentication section, and also the transport section).
Input will be somethnig like this:
curl -X POST -k -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{"msg":"Hi, I am testing"}' \
  --cert /path/to/client-crt.pem \
  --key  /path/to/client-key.pem \
  --cacret /path/to/ca-crt.pem \
  https://localhost:8000/testing

# It will submit something like: {'msg': 'Hi, I am testing'}

Expected:
{
  "msg": "Hi, I am testing",
  "_meta": {
    "timestamp": "2024-08-23....",
    "host": "localhost",
    "client": "C=UK/ST=London/O=Org/OU=Unit/CN=Username"
  }
}

